# Which PC hardware would you recommend to invest in for movement ecology studies in R (x,y,t data analysis)?

Tags: r, hardware

I mean all possible work with tagging data: GIS, tagging data pre-processing, visualisation, different types of modelling, simulations and modern analysis.

I think it will be about 40 tagged animals and maximum 30-40 thousand total locations to work with.

The tools that I will probably use are described here: https://www.movebank.org/panel_software